# order active_admin column by parent item in belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activeadmin

I have two models: `show_request` and `show`.  A `show_Request` belongs_to a `show` and a `show` has_many `show_requests`.  On the `show_request` page in active_admin, I want to order `show_requests` by the `show`'s `created_at` value.  Here is my code so far:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ShowRequest do

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.includes(:show)
      #I also tried ShowRequest.includes(:show)
    end
  end

  index do
    column 'Show', sortable: "shows.created_at_asc" do |show_req|
        link_to show_req.show.name, admin_show_path(show_req.show)
    end
  end

end
```

Here are the server logs:

```
Started GET "/admin/show_requests" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-18 09:35:36 -0400
Processing by Admin::ShowRequestsController#index as HTML
  AdminUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users"  WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "show_requests"  WHERE (not_going_to_show = 'f' OR i_want_my_horse_to_compete = 't')
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "show_requests"
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "show_requests"  WHERE (not_going_to_show = 't' AND i_want_my_horse_to_compete = 'f')
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "show_requests"  WHERE (not_going_to_show = 'f' OR i_want_my_horse_to_compete = 't') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "show_requests"  WHERE (not_going_to_show = 'f' OR i_want_my_horse_to_compete = 't') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "show_requests"  WHERE (not_going_to_show = 'f' OR i_want_my_horse_to_compete = 't')
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "show_requests"  WHERE (not_going_to_show = 'f' OR i_want_my_horse_to_compete = 't') LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
  ShowRequest Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "show_requests".* FROM "show_requests"  WHERE (not_going_to_show = 'f' OR i_want_my_horse_to_compete = 't')  ORDER BY "show_requests"."id" desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  Show Load (9.7ms)  SELECT "shows".* FROM "shows"  WHERE "shows"."id" IN (2, 1)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Show Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shows".* FROM "shows"
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
```

This is not working.  It is not affecting the order of the columns at all.  How do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487477/rails-3-activeadmin-how-to-set-a-default-sort-order-for-an-associated-record

Comment: Athar, I tried that but it did nothing.  no change at all.

Comment: well what happen if you remove `_asc` part from the sortable line. change like this `column 'Show', sortable: "shows.created_at" do |show_req|`

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it also does nothing. What's interesting is that no matter what I write, there is no effect.  for example, if I write  `shows.created_at_fdskjfsdlkj` there is no difference.

Comment: hmmm according to the doc http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html #Associated Sorting if you add this `super.includes :show` in `scoped_collection` action and in showing column you do this `column "Show", sortable: 'shows.created_at'` it should work, it just tries to access that column from association.

Comment: Hmm, yea I'm not sure why it's not working

Comment: It should work with `sortable: "shows.created_at"`. Dumb question, but are you sure you added timestamps in your `CreateShows` migration?

Comment: Ha, yes I added timestamps

Comment: Can you check your logs and verify that the SQL generated actually performs a join? If not, try tacking `.references(:show)` on to the end of your scoped collection. More information here: http://www.foraker.com/blog/active-record-includes-query-logic

Comment: @ahmacleod, I added the server logs to the question content.  Does that seem right to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this part of the log:

```
ShowRequest Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "show_requests".* FROM "show_requests"  WHERE (not_going_to_show = 'f' OR i_want_my_horse_to_compete = 't')  ORDER BY "show_requests"."id" desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
Show Load (9.7ms)  SELECT "shows".* FROM "shows"  WHERE "shows"."id" IN (2, 1)
```

You can see that the `ShowRequest`s and `Show`s are loaded in separate queries. `sortable` is not going to work here, because you can't order one table by a field of another without a join. The fix should be to tell ActiveRecord that you need to reference the `shows` table in your query:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    super.includes(:show).references(:shows)
  end
end

index do
  column :show, sortable: 'shows.created_at'
end
```

`references` only works with `includes`, and forces Rails to perform a join when eager loading.

Comment: Thanks?  Should it be :shows or :show?  Includes isn't working with :shows so I changed it to :show.  It still isn't affecting the order though, although it is changing the server logs

Comment: You're right, it should be `:show` for the `includes`, but still `:shows` for `references`.

Comment: It should be `shows.created_at`. For both references and sortable, you're referencing the table name.

Comment: Thanks ahmacleod, tried that but no change, except the server logs are now different.  It won't let me put my logs in the comment though.  It says they're too long.  Is there another way to put them up?